# Java - length of a buffer to write a file

Tags: java, arrays, buffer

This is a question concerning setting the size of a byte array for a buffer to write() a local file from a URL stream:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[26];
```

26 seems to be the magic number. If I put anything above 26 (say 1024), it still only writes the first 26 characters into the file. Why? Please note that I'm not trying to write the entire stream (using the while loop) just trying to figure out why the biggest chunk is only 26 characters long.

Here's the full code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class ReadNetworkFile {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        File f2 = new File("target3.txt");

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
            URL url = new URL("http://services.explorecalifornia.org/rss/tours.php");
            InputStream stream = url.openStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int len=stream.read(buffer);

            out.write(buffer,0,len);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the magic ingredient: the `while-loop`.

You need to read from the web and write to the file while len > 0. Then you've finished.

Comment: I'm not trying to write the entire content of the stream, just the first chunk. I'm just testing the buffer size. Why is it limited to 26 characters is my question.

Comment: It's not limited to 26 bytes. In your case the TCP/IP connection just happens to make the first package's payload 26 bytes. It will be different on different environments so don't draw any conclusions from the "magic number" 26.

Comment: No need to be rude, but yes, that does answer my question. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I'm not trying to be rude, but as I said, I'm hungover.